# New to Command Prompt - Do I need to prefix every command with "Jruby -S ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmd, command, jruby

I'm new to using Window's Command Prompt, and also to developing with Ruby on Rails.  Possibly a silly question but one that I'm sure everyone who learns with CodeCademy will end up asking; right now I'm prefixing every command for my project with 'Jruby -S ...", for example:

```
C:\users\MyName\MyProject> Jruby -S rails new MyApp
...    
C:\users\MyName\MyProject> Jruby -S bundle install
...
C:\users\MyName\MyProject> Jruby -S rake db:migrate
```

Can I use some kind of alternative shell to save me typing Jruby -S every time?  I'm aware of bash and powershell but have basically zero knowledge of whether I should be using them...

Thanks folks!

---

EDIT
Lots of helpful suggestions below, but I was really looking for a shell to mimic the functionality of the console on codecademy.com (which I believe is supposed to work like a Mac's 'bash' program?).  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new to using Window's Command Prompt

The CMD works very similarly to the GUI/Shell -- you have to call `applications` and then run *commands* with them.

The difference between `CMD` and `windows` is that CMD is "naked" - you have to ensure all the paths are correct, and that you're calling the correct application each time.

For example, calling `rails server` *literally* translates as:

> - Program = `ruby.exe / rails`
> - Command = `server`

CMD uses the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) to make this process smoother.

The PATH var basically allows you to reference applications on your computer from the [CLI (command line interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). This means that if you have an application (EG `ruby.exe`), you can add the `ruby.exe` directory to your `PATH` variable, allowing you to call `ruby ...` straight from `cmd`.

--

In your case, I don't have much experience with `JRuby`; I *do* know, however, that if you want to invoke the functionality of that application, you have to call it from the cli.

Hopefully my answer gives some context.

Comment: Thanks for that Rich, explains why I need to keep typing 'Jruby -S'! I was hoping there would be a simple way to carry on without it, i.e. use a different shell(?), but I guess not.

Comment: If `JRuby` is in your path, that's the best you can do for now. Is there any reason you're using `JRuby` over just pure Ruby? If you're using `ruby`, you can call `rails s` without any specific reference to `ruby`

Comment: Only that it's what the Heroku tutorial suggested.  I'm on Windows, which could explain why the Jruby installation is preferred?

Comment: JRuby is java-centric ruby. I've never used it, so I don't know its virtues or pitfalls. If you're using pure ruby (for Rails development), without any specific java requirements, you'll be best looking at [`RubyInstaller`](http://rubyinstaller.org) or [`RailsInstaller`](http://railsinstaller.org) to get a pure version of Ruby installed. I can write a tutorial if you want, it's a little tricky to get it all installed on Windows!

Comment: I'll look in to that! Beginning to wonder why Heroku recommends using Jruby?! Thanks again Rich.

Comment: You have to remember most devs use linux, so their recommendations can be biased ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with powershell.
I'm sure that there should be a better way to do that, but you can try this

```
$ruby = "Jruby"
$s = "-S"

& $ruby $s rails new MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work on windows, however the jruby zip files on the download site have a bin directory with .bat and .exe files for jruby, rake, and gem. You could just add the directory you installed jruby to and the 'bin' subdirectory to your PATH to start.

set JRUBY_HOME= your_installed_jruby
set PATH= %PATH%;%JRUBY_HOME%\bin

http://jruby.org/download

I don't know what the windows installer does, but I would think it would do something similar.